# New value must be greater and diferrent

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I'm trying to compare the value entered by user (`$b`) with another value which is retrieved from my database tables (`$a`).

In theory, the below code should retrieve error 1 but it's not. Can you please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
{$a=array('54607');
$b=array('54606');

if($a < $b){
   echo "error 1";
}elseif($a == $b){
   echo "error 2";
}else{
   echo "TRUE";
}
```

P.S. I'm a newbie in PHP so please be gentle and sorry in advance for any silly questions I may have.

Comment: Why do you have to use these as arrays? can't they be simple variables?

Comment: Yes it can also be a simple variable. I've tried your examples below and they still give "TRUE", but as you can see $b it's less than $a so i need to have error 1.

Comment: Please check your condition. It prints TRUE when none of the condition follows. a is neither less than b, nor is it equal to b. So it comes to the else condition and prints TRUE

Comment: Can you please help me with a condition that will return error 1 for the example above? From what i've read < means, as in math , strictly less than so the first condition should apply and it should show ' error 1' but it doesn't and it goes on and it checks the other conditions and since than one it's not applying too it returns true.

Comment: a is 54607 and b is 54606..how is a less than b? Have you even checked what you have posted? And if you want to reverse your condition, use $a > $b

Comment: You are right sorry my big mistake. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a=54607;
$b=54606;

if($a < $b){echo "error 1";
}elseif($a == $b){echo "error 2";
}else{echo "TRUE";}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to print **error 1** change your condition to a > b.

You should remove these **array** notation and define these as simple variables.

```
$a = 54607;
$b = 54606;

if ($a > $b) {
   echo "error 1";
} elseif($a == $b) {
   echo "error 2";
} else {
   echo "TRUE";
}
```

In case these has to be made arrays, use current() function:

```
$a = array('54607');
$b = array('54606');
if (current($a) > current($b)) {
   echo "error 1";
} elseif(current($a) == current($b)) {
   echo "error 2";
} else {
   echo "TRUE";
}
```